# How can I upload multiple files using vue.js and multer?

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, multer

I am able to upload a single file using multer. But when it comes to multiple files it won't work anymore and no file is caught by multer.

I send files through formData.append(). But it only uploads single file

`Vue component`

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("productImg", this.imgFile);
this.$store.dispatch(POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE, formData)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

`Server file`

```
const uploadPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../../public/uploads');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, uploadPath + "/garbage/productImg");
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        var newName = Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname;
        callback(null, newName);
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});

productRouter.post('/uploadProductImage', upload.any(), async (req, res) => { // Some Code })
```

I did also

```
productRouter.post('/uploadProductImage', array('productImg[]', 6), async (req, res) => { // Some Code })
```

I want to upload multiple files at a time to my specified folder.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found a solution which is very silly though.

In Vue component file i just use a loop before add in formData. Like this.

> Vue Component

```
const formData = new FormData();
// formData.append("productImg", this.imgFile); // OLD ONE
for (let index = 0; index < this.imgFile.length; index++) { //NEW ONE
  let file = this.imgFile[index];
  formData.append("productImg["+index+"]", file);
}
this.$store.dispatch(POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE, formData)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

Comment: Amazing code buddy